# Plotting symbolic functions Matlab parameters

Tags: matlab, plot, param

I would like to know how to plot functions with parameters in matlab. 
For example, the electric potential is described as V(d)=1/(4pi*eps0*d^2)
I would like to plot the electric potential as a symbolic function but to choose which variable to plot as the independent variable. 
For example, V(d) or V(eps)... How to tell matlab that d is the variable and eps id the parameter? 
Thanks very much

Comment: Please make some attempt to solve your problem yourself. There is more than enough information on the internet on how to plot functions in Matlab. This is a very basic question you can easily find an answer for.

Answer (score 2):

I would go this way:

```
syms d;
syms eps;
V = 1./(4.*pi.*eps.*d.^2);
```

You may think of using `ezplot` capabilities; for instance, you could call

```
ezplot(subs(V,eps,0.1))
ezplot(subs(V,d,0.1))
```

In the previous two lines you are saying:

1) plot `V` depending on `d` and `eps = 0.1`;

2) plot `V` depending on `eps` and `d = 0.1`.

I hope this helps.